# Преобразовать строку в длинное число

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, вектор

Есть вектор длины `n` и строка длины `m`, содержащая только цифры. Необходимо в вектор записывать числа с максимум `k` цифрами, содержащиеся в строке, с конца. Например:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> v(3); // n = 3
std::string s = "52152000535"; // m = 11 (без `\n`)
size_t k = 4;
// в итоге в векторе должно быть следующее
v[0] == 535; // т.е. начальные нули отбрасываются
v[1] == 5200;
v[2] == 521; // т.е. если цифр не хватает, то берём всё, что осталось
```

Все параметры правильно согласованны, т.е. конфликтов нет, строка содержит исключительно цифры, нули не могут идти первыми.

У меня есть решение вида "для каждого элемента вектора берём нужную подстроку с конца с помощью `substr()` и преобразуем её в число с помощью `stoll()`", но решение использует несколько счётчиков и вероятность багов очень высока. Было бы прекрасно иметь решение с помощью итераторов и STL алгоритмов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямолинейный подход к решению может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    size_t n = 3;
    size_t k = 4;

    std::vector<unsigned int> v(n);
    std::string s( "52152000535");

    size_t m = s.size();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n && m != 0; i++ )
    {
        size_t length = std::min(k, m);
        m -= length;
        v[i] = static_cast<unsigned int>(std::stoul(s.substr(m, length)));
    }

    for (auto x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
535 5200 521
```

Нет никакой необходимости здесь искусственно прилеплять алгоритмы, тем более, если такое решение с алгоритмами, если оно существует, не очевидно.

Answer (score 0):

Без STL, с одним счётчиком

```
std::vector<unsigned int> v; 
std::string s = "52152000535"; 
size_t k = 4;
size_t str_size = s.size();
int i;

for (i = str_size - k; i > 0; i -= k)
    v.push_back(std::stoi(s.substr(i, k)));

v.push_back(std::stoi(s.substr(0, i+k)));
```

Не очень понятно, почему вы используете std::stoll хотя вектор содержит unsigned int

Comment: ... и после замечания про `stoll` вы вдруг использовали `stoi`? Если выбирать из этих двух, то `stoll` как раз таки уместнее.

Comment: @AnT не очень понял вашу претензию. Про stoll это мое замечание автору. Я изначально код писал с stoi. Потом обратил внимание, что автор использует stoll. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему stoll уместнее для типа unsigned int